# Does NginX(Open source, not Nginx plus), supports API Gateway?

Tags: api, nginx, gateway

Does NginX(Open source, not Nginx plus), supports API Gateway?
Please, help me get to the valid documentation or information. Thank you!

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you mean. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: We are in sales pitch phase. We are considering on Nginx products, for API gateway. I see enough documentations, with respect to Nginx plus, whereas, curious to know if Nginx open source has any API gateaway intelligence? kindly, help!

Comment: If you choose not to go NGINX Plus, then you'll have to proxy to a WSGI which will make calls to your API.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately the Nginx Api Gateway is featured only in Nginx Plus. But there is [Kong](https://getkong.org/), an alternative that is built on top of Nginx and is also open source.

There is even a post on Nginx's official blog about it: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-powers-kong-api-management-solution/

**Edit**: The blog post has been replaced by an nginx plus one. The original post can still be accessed through web.archive.org:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160413082936/https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-powers-kong-api-management-solution/

Comment: The blog post redirects and is no longer about kong.

Comment: Thanks @BenG, I've included that info in the answer and also a link for the original post.